# Create a table in SQL Server where the name is a variable in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Using Visual Studio and SSMS.

I have a form where a user registers a username and it's stored like this:

```
List<SqlParameter> sqlNewTable = new List<SqlParameter>();
sqlNewTable.Add(new SqlParameter("Username", txtUser.Text));
DAL.ExecSP("CreateUserCourses", sqlNewTable);
```

From there, can I create a stored procedure called `CreateUserCourses` in which it creates a new table where the users input (their username) is the name of a new table?

Comment: Yes you can. But why?

Comment: To sum it up, it's a test program where you view courses you've taken. The user makes an account, a table would be made based on their username, inside it would be a copy of the master Course list, then the user can select options to change it. I'm okay with knowing how to change things but can't figure out how to make a table in SSMS and name it using a variable in Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you do any research? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f8f50eee-2393-4d18-8350-30cea6d480a4/create-table-with-variable-name?forum=transactsql

Comment: @tryingtotryhard this will make your life very very hard. I would recommend you to read up on relational databases before you go further with this approach.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Thank you. I tried googling what I could but I guess I'm just going about it wrong and wasn't googling the right way to go about it. :/

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, but why?

Supposing you have a `User` table and a `Course` table. Then just make a 3rd table which maps those tables together Called `UserCourses`. This  is called a Many-to-Many (mapping table) and it will containing an ID of both the `User`, and `Course` and any other relevant information .

This will make your life a lot easier going forward

[Many-to-many (data model)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model))

> A many-to-many relationship is a type of cardinality that refers to
>   the relationship between two entities[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) A and B in which A may
>   contain a parent instance for which there are many children in B and
>   vice versa.
>
> For example, think of A as Authors, and B as Books. An Author can
>   write several Books, and a Book can be written by several Authors

**Example**

```
student: student_id, first_name, last_name
classes: class_id, name, teacher_id
student_classes: class_id, student_id     // mapping table
```

**SQL queries could look like this**

Getting all students for a class

```
SELECT s.student_id, last_name
FROM student_classes sc 
INNER JOIN students s ON s.student_id = sc.student_id
WHERE sc.class_id = X
```

Getting all classes for a student

```
SELECT c.class_id, name
FROM student_classes sc 
INNER JOIN classes c ON c.class_id = sc.class_id
WHERE sc.student_id = Y
```

**Entity framework queries could look like this**

Getting all students for a class

```
var students = db.Students.Where(x => x.StudentClasses
                                       .Any(y => y.ClassId == 1);
```

Getting all classes for a student

```
var classes = db.classes.Where(x => x.StudentClasses
                                     .Any(y => y.StudentId == 1);
```

Comment: I'm really new to databases so I'm not sure how to do that... I'll look into that, thank you.